# How to pass jenkins credentials to karate framework?

Tags: jenkins, karate

I have user credentials stored in Jenkins credentials and i need to pass them to my karate framework (gradle build). Can anyone suggest any way to do that?

I am able to run the framework via normal pipeline when i am adding the creds to the script, but want to figure out a way to do that via jenkins as i dont want to store creds in my script.